# Laravel: while hosting xampp on localhost in mac getting an error UnexpectedValueException

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, backend, server-side

I am just starting with laravel, when I localhost it in xampp(localhost:8080/app/public) in mac [where app is a file created when I created] it shows an error

```
`UnexpectedValueException
The stream or file "/opt/lampp/htdocs/app/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied`
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: try `sudo chmod -R 0777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/app/storage/logs`

Comment: improve formating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that laravel doesn't have permissions to create logs so come to the root directory of the project and run this command from your terminal

```
sudo chmod -R 775 .
```

in your case, your project is in this path `/opt/lampp/htdocs/app` so move to it first then change permissions like this

```
$ cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/app
$ sudo chmod -R 775 .
```

Comment: I've to use `777` not `775`!